# r - Count the number of ranks in a paired sample

Tags: r, testing, sign, rank

I'm essentially given a paired sample say:

```
X = c(14, 5, 2, 8 , 9, 10)

Y = c(7, 3, 4, 13, 11, 12)
```

If I sort and pair the two samples into say Z what function can I use to record the number of ranks in Z?

```
Z = c(2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
```

so Z is now

```
Z = (X, Y, Y, Y, X, X, X, Y, Y, Y, X)
```

How do i count the number of X-runs which in this case is 3 of sizes 1, 2 and 1
I've tried the rle() function but I don't understand how to return the different X and Y's

Comment: Your `Z = (X, Y, Y, ...)` doesn't match your `Z = c(2,3,4...)`. It should be `Z = (X, Y, Y, Y, X, X, X, Y, Y, Y)`

Comment: 5 is missing in Z. Also, what is your desired output? `table(rle(Z))`? `colSums(table(rle(Z2)))`?

Comment: `rle(Z %in% X)$lengths[rle(Z %in% X)$values]`

Comment: The question is interesting, but your example still doesn't match what you're asking. 12 values in X/Y become 10 in Z, and then 11 in Z; 5 and 14 are missing from Z, and your expected result doesn't match Z (1/2/1 instead of 1/3/1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the number of runs of each value in `Z`, you can use `rle()`, firstly by finding which values of `Z` are in `X or Y`, then subsetting that again on the values that are `TRUE`

```
rle(Z %in% X)$lengths[rle(Z %in% X)$values]
#[1] 1 3
rle(Z %in% Y)$lengths[rle(Z %in% Y)$values]
#[1] 3 3
```

Which, as @docendo discimus points out can be written as

```
with(rle(Z %in% X), lengths[values])
with(rle(Z %in% Y), lengths[values])
```

---

Where

```
Z %in% X ## gives
TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So then using `rle` on the `TRUE/FALSE` vector gives us our **runs** of each `TRUE/FALSE`

```
rle(Z %in% X)  ## gives
    Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:4] 1 3 3 3
  values : logi [1:4] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

So we can take the `lenghts` and `values` components separately, and subset the `lenghts` where `values == TRUE`

---

**Data**

```
X <- c(14, 5, 2, 8 , 9, 10)
Y <- c(7, 3, 4, 13, 11, 12)
Z <- c(2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13)
```

Comment: Or just `rle(Z)$lengths[rle(Z)$values == 'X']` and `rle(Z)$lengths[rle(Z)$values == 'Y']`, no?

Comment: @alistaire I've assumed that his `Z` is the `Z <- c(2, 3, 4, ...)` one, and that the `Z = (X, Y, Y, ...)` is a representation of the `Z`...

Comment: Oh, I see. I used `Z2 <- ifelse(is.na(pmatch(Z, X)), 'Y', 'X')` to make the second version.

Comment: If you want to avoid computing the run lengths twice (unnecessarily), you can use `with(rle(Z %in% X), lengths[values])`

Comment: @docendodiscimus - yes, a good addition. I'll include it in my answer. Thanks.